# Unity 5 2D drawing sprites programmatically

Tags: c#, unity

How can I draw sprites in Unity 5 programmatically ? I am looking for something similar to `spriteBatch.Draw()` in XNA. The results I get when I search about it are either outdated http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SpriteManager (this was written in 2012), or they are done using the unity interface. All I can find is a `Sprite` class in UnityEngine.dll. Is this what I need ? How would the drawing work ? I really don't get it.

Comment: What do you mean by drawing sprites? You mean rendering them to the screen or dynamically creating the image represented by the sprite?

Comment: @Byte56 rendering a 2D image on the screen, just like every 2D game engine i have seen does. I don't know why this seems to be so frustratingly hard to find when you search in google. I need something like spriteBatch.Draw(SpriteSheetName, position, Rectangle, origin, scale, rotation) where the rectangle is defining the part of the sprite-sheet i am trying to draw. I am now trying to do this by making a `Sprite` and then a `SpriteRenderer` but i can't figure out how to set an image to the sprite.

Comment: @Byte56 `Sprite` objects don't seem to even have a property to set the image. the closest thing i see is sprite.texture which is read only... actually every property of sprite is read only

Comment: As a complement, altought you cannot draw sprites, you can draw meshes without creating a gameobject using Graphics.DrawMesh, so teorically you could draw a 2d texture over a plane programmatically, but I would recommend to use a GameObject with Sprite renderer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unity does not have this kind of "direct mode" rendering, you won't be calling `Draw` in any update loops for Unity.

In Unity you need to create a game object, then attach scripts to that game object. Those scripts will control how the object behaves, if and how it's displayed on screen, if it's part of the physics system etc.

To create a new sprite to draw on screen you'll need to create a new game object, then attach the SpriteRenderer script to it and set its sprite.

```
GameObject go = new GameObject();
SpriteRenderer renderer = go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

renderer.sprite = Resources.Load("Sprites/Player", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

This assumes a directory structure of

```
-Assets
--Resources
---Sprites
----<Your 2D assets, set with their texture type to Sprite (2D and UI)>
```

For example:

[image]

Then you'd had a different script for changing the position, rotation etc, depending how you want it to behave.

The easiest way to accomplish all of this without having to write as much code? Create the game object in the Unity editor first. Once the game object is equipped with the sprite you want and the behavior scripts and all that. Drag and drop it into a resources directory. This creates a prefab. Prefabs are just what they sound like, pre-fabrications. They're complete objects that you can then reference and create on the fly.

You'd create those like:

```
public void CreateObject(string prefabName) {
   GameObject newObject = 
      GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load(prefabName)) as GameObject;
}
```

This will spawn a clone of the prefab you created before. So, if for example, you'd given your prefab the behavior of moving towards the player and attacking, every time you spawn a new prefab of that type, they will start moving towards the player and attacking. The scripts you only had to write once control all of those game objects.

I think the main difference you're seeing here is the heavy use of components. Which you likely haven't seen in other game engines like XNA. Unity really is a powerful engine, but your frustration comes from trying to use it like other engines, when it's not like other engines. Check out my profile for some training, I added a link for a free trial so you don't have to pay.

Comment: wow. my knowledge of unity just increased by a ton :) this makes a lot of sense actually. i never heard of prefabs before. thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: also i just started watching your tutorials :D

Comment: @Shiro You may want to browse the basic ones first, to solidify your understanding of Unity objects, components, prefabs, etc. Also, don't mind the GUI chapter of my course :( it's out of date.

Comment: oh good to know, and yes i started from the first one

Comment: um, since there is no spritebatch in unity to batch the sprites, i am wondering do you know if is there a any performance increase when using spritesheets vs many single sprites in unity ? because in the asset store i see sprite sheets. is that for usability inside the unity interface or actual performance ?

Comment: Sounds like a new question for the site, not the comments.

Comment: This answer should be printed on the first page of Unity docs.