# Equivalent to Draw() method in Unity project?

Tags: xna, unity, monogame

I have been using xna/monogame before this. So I read tutorials about unity, made some classes, loaded some sprites, everything "seems" to be going good, but I can't figure out how to add things into the environment, could anyone tell me or guide me to what's the equivalent of Monogame's Draw() method in Unity? Thank you.

Comment: i asked the same question yesterday http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96058/unity-5-2d-drawing-sprites-programmatically

Comment: @Shiro Awesome! :) I'll check the answer out right now, thanks!

Comment: check the comments as well

Comment: So basically, you create a game object, give it the desired sprite, and then work on scripts to simply alter its behavior, movement, and such? I think I understand that, I also understand making it a "prefab", and being able to clone it and re-create it instantly. But what of animation loops? In XNA I'm used for example to having 4 - 5 images that create a .gif like sequence, I make a loop in the update method, and load every image one after another, whereas in unity, if I make a game object i'll have to assign one image, to one sprite. So is there any alternative to what I want?

Comment: for sprite animations there is also an automated way of doing it through the unity interface for that there are many tutorials. I haven't done it myself yet, because i just got started yesterday with unity and im watching tutorials still, but i am pretty sure there are play/stop animation methods, and basically every other thing you need. you should search for it

Comment: I just got started today with unity as well. Good luck to both of us then! :) I think I got the hang of most of it until now thanks to the unity video tutos http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting

Comment: the way i see it is, since you have used monogame before and have the experience of doing every single thing yourself with code, you already have the knowledge so you are not missing out on anything. Unity is basically doing every boring/time-consuming stuff through an the interface, and the code you write is basically the core game logic in the form of scripts. i didn't seem to like that at first at all but now i understand why it is done this way. it is just for performance, saving time and re-usability of code with the preflabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity doesn't have XNA equivalent for Draw method. There are some low level helpers, but don't think it's need until you'll try to do something more complex.

Unity takes care of rendering instead of doing the manually. Add GameObjects to scene and attach components like MeshRenderer, SpriteRenderer or some other. And it will be put into rendering queue automatically.
To control rendering order there SortingLayer, SortingOrder, DrawQueue(in shader), Layering property, so it's enough to make complex scenes with custom behaviuors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this without SpriteRenderers using [Graphics.DrawMesh()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMesh.html). You can use this method to draw sprites by using [properties that sprites have](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html) like vertices, triangles, uv, texture, etc. to construct a mesh and appropriate material.

Here is an example

```
public class SpriteDrawer : MonoBehaviour {

// A list of textures we want to build materials for beforehand
// Using the same material saves draw calls
public List<Texture2D> textures;
public Material spriteMaterial;

Dictionary<Texture2D, Material> textureMats = new Dictionary<Texture2D, Material>();

public void Awake() {
    //fill up textureMats with materials
    foreach (Texture2D texture in textures) {
        textureMats.Add(texture, new Material(spriteMaterial) {
            mainTexture = texture
        });
    }
}

public void Draw(Sprite sprite, Vector3 pos) {
    Material mat;
    //check if we already made a prebuilt material, otherwise make a new one
    if (textureMats.ContainsKey(sprite.texture)) {
        mat = textureMats[sprite.texture];
    } else {
        mat = new Material(spriteMaterial) {
            mainTexture = sprite.texture
        };
    }
    //build a mesh for the sprite
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh() {
        vertices = Array.ConvertAll(sprite.vertices, x => (Vector3)x),
        triangles = Array.ConvertAll(sprite.triangles, x => (int)x),
        uv = sprite.uv
    };
    Graphics.DrawMesh(mesh, Matrix4x4.TRS(pos, Quaternion.identity, sprite.bounds.size), mat, 0);
}
}
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this script so it may or may not work