# How can I initialize a sprite programmatically in Unity

Tags: textures, rendering, sprites, platformer

Hello everyone and thank you so much for your help!
I've tried following the answer at [Unity 5 2D drawing sprites programmatically](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96058/unity-5-2d-drawing-sprites-programmatically) but nothing happened.  I have a blank screen with just a background image (my game is 2d).  I want to programmatically create 6 (or more) platforms (rectangles) one above another in the center of the camera view.  If you've played the game Doodle Jump - that's sort of what I want to accomplish, but the movement is for a later day.  My background is in swift and SpriteKit developing for iOS.  I'm completely stumped here.  I've tried to create a gameObject and then add the component SpriteRenderer and then tried to create a square texture which I can scale into a rectangle.  But no platforms appear.  I'm really at a loss of what to do because I don't see how to create a sprite.  I've tried the Sprite.Create method but that didn't work for me either.  Please will you help me?

Comment: Please show us the code you've written, how you've set up your scene, and what you see in the scene view, hierarchy, and console tabs when the script is running.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I've found a solution so I'll write that below

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution while looking through a tutorial. I created a prefab of the platform I wanted to programmatically create. Then I wrote the following inside a `for` loop:

```
GameObject platform = Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

This created the 6 platforms I needed through iteration. `spawnPositon.y` increased at every loop. `Quaternion.Identity` is so the platforms aren't rotated.